# How to specify specific qt version in mxe

Tags: qt, qt5, mxe

I need to use qt version 5.5 with mxe but dont find any option. I only see qt which is 4.8.7 and qt5 which is 5.8
Am I restricted to one of the two versions or is there any option to use 5.5 also.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is example how to freeze Qt version https://github.com/mxe/mxe/tree/master/plugins/examples/qt5-freeze

You need to copy that plugin folder and edit it to change to a version you need.

And than use it by adding mxe additional argument **MXE_PLUGIN_DIRS**='plugin dir path'